# Practicing For loop to search through an array consisting of multiple objects and properties

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I'm practicing For loop and below is the data provided for me. It's an array consisting of objects with contact details.

```
const contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "Akira",
    lastName: "Laine",
    number: "0543236543",
    likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    lastName: "Potter",
    number: "0994372684",
    likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    lastName: "Holmes",
    number: "0487345643",
    likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
  },
];
```

The idea is to use the function below to search the `name` inside the array and then checking whether `prop` exists in that name.
`function lookUpProfile(name, prop)`

- if Name exists inside the `contacts` array, then I have to check whether `prop` exists in that name.
- If the `prop` doesn't exist, return "No such property"
- If `name` doesnt exist in the array, return "No such contact".

Below is the answer

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for (let i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
     if (contacts[i].firstName===name) {
         if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
             return contacts[i][prop];
         } else {
             return "No such property";
         }
     }
  }
  return "No such contact"
}
```

What i want to know is why do I have to put "No such contact" outside the For loop? shouldn't it be inside the loop?

Comment: If it's inside the loop, it'll always return after the first iteration and won't continue the loop.

Comment: but there are 2 returns inside the for loop, though. Why dont they terminate the loop?

Comment: They do - based on the conditionals. But you want to search all the Objects for the correct name before returning "No such contact."

Comment: Both inner `return` statements are associated with the `if` condition.  "No such contact" is returned when none of the contacts meet the condition `contacts[i].firstName===name`; the `if` statement is never executed when that happens.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I still don't understand the logic of this. Shouldn't "No such contact" be an `else` result for the first `if` when checking whether the name exists?

Comment: No.  `else` is not required.  If the loop completes without finding a match, it simply drops into the next statement, which is `return "No such contact"`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey i'm starting to understand a little bit. Please bear with me. So, the loop will first go through the first `if`, to check whether the name exists. If it doesn't exist on the first loop, it will check for the next `i`. So if the loop couldn't find anything, and if i write `return "No such contact"` INSIDE the loop, then it will stop on the first iteration, right? So if i put "Harry", since it's the second name in the array, the loop would've stopped too early before it reaches "Harry". Am i understanding it correctly?

Comment: No.  The loop will first check each contact against the condition `contacts[i].firstName===name`.  If it never finds a contact that meets this condition, the inner `if` statement is never executed.  The inner `if` statement only executes if the loop finds a contact that meets the condition `contacts[i].firstName===name`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes i understand up to that point. what i'm trying to say is, if i put the `return "No such contact"` INSIDE the loop, then when the program runs its first loop and didn't find "Harry" (second name in the array), it will go to `return "No such contact"` and then just stops the program entirely. It won't continue a second time because it's been terminated too early.

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thank you so much for the explanation! everything seems obvious now. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this function :

```
function lookUpProfile(contacts, name, prop) {
    let result = contacts.find(contact => contact.firstName == name);
    return result ? (result[prop] ? result[prop] : "No such property" ) : "No such contact";
}

console.log(lookUpProfile(contacts, 'Sherlock', 'number'));
```

Comment: Why ? .........

Comment: I'm a beginner in javascript here, lol. I don't even know what `find` is currently. This method is what the lesson module asked me to do

Comment: No probleme, I just share my own version of this function as I think it's intersting to compare with your. If you're a beginner then it might help you to understand how does js array / object works. Just wanted to help you, I can't delete if it doesn't interest you ;)

Comment: it's okay. i could go back to this page when i learn about the more complex stuff. Thank  you for taking the time to reply!

Comment: No probleme, good training ;)